# ValueError during tensorflow graph construction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to train a GAN using tensorflow, but during graph construction I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1_1 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

I'm guessing this is because my discriminator and generator are within different functions which I'm calling. I would ideally want to avoid rolling my entire architecture out of methods, as this would lead to a tediously-long python file.

I've tried using a default value for the placeholders before the first training examples are pushed through a sess.run() call, but this led to the same example being run through the graph at each stage of training (probably because that's how tensorflow constructed the graph)

My training loop code is below. Please let me know if seeing the generator and discriminator functions themselves would help.

```
    img1 = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32)
    img2 = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32)
    lr = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32)

    synthetic_imgs, synthetic_logits, mse, _ = self.gen(img1)
    fake_result, fake_logits_hr, fake_feature_2 = self.disc(img1, synthetic_imgs)
    ground_truth_result, ground_truth_logits_hr, truth_feature_2 = self.disc(img1, img2)

    _, fake_logits_lr = self.disc_two(img1, synthetic_imgs)
    _, ground_truth_logits_lr = self.disc_two(img1, img2)

    a = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

    dis_labels = tf.random.uniform((self.batch_size, 1), minval = -0.2, maxval = 0.3)
    gen_labels = tf.random.uniform((self.batch_size, 1), minval = 0.75, maxval = 1.2)
    dis_loss = #Discriminator Loss

    gen_loss = #Generator Loss

    #May want to change to -log(MSE)
    d_vars = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if 'disc' in var.name]
    g_vars = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if 'g_' in var.name]

    dis_loss = tf.reduce_mean(dis_loss)
    gen_loss = tf.reduce_mean(gen_loss)

    with tf.variable_scope('optimizers', reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE) as scope:           
        gen_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = lr, name = 'gen_opt')
        disc_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = lr, name = 'dis_opt')

    gen1 = gen_opt.minimize(gen_loss, var_list = g_vars)
    disc1 = disc_opt.minimize(dis_loss, var_list = d_vars)

    #Tensorboard code for visualizing gradients
    #global_step = variable_scope.get_variable("global_step", [], trainable=False, dtype=dtypes.int64, initializer=init_ops.constant_initializer(0, dtype=dtypes.int64))

    # gen_training = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(gen_loss, global_step, learning_rate=lr, optimizer=gen_opt, summaries=["gradients"], variables = g_vars)
    # disc_training = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(dis_loss, global_step, learning_rate=lr, optimizer=disc_opt, summaries=["gradients"], variables = d_vars)

    #summary = tf.summary.merge_all()


    with tf.Session() as sess:  
        print('start session')      

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        #print(tf.trainable_variables()) #Find variable corresponding to conv filter weights, which you can use for tensorboard visualization
        #Code to load each training example

        gen = self.pairs()

        for i in range(self.num_epochs):
            print(str(i+ 1) + 'th epoch')
            for j in range(self.num_batches):

                i_1 = None
                i_2 = None
                #Crektes batch
                for k in range(self.batch_size):
                    p = next(gen)
                    try:
                        i_1 = np.concatenate((i1, self.load_img(p[0])), axis = 0)
                        i_2 = np.concatenate((i2, self.load_img(p[1])), axis = 0)
                    except Exception:
                        i_1 = self.load_img(p[0])
                        i_2 = self.load_img(p[1])

                l_r = 8e-4 * (0.5)**(i//100) #Play around with this value
                test, gLoss, _ = sess.run([img1, gen_loss, gen1], feed_dict = {i1 : i_1, i2 : i_2, learn_rate : l_r})
                dLoss, _ = sess.run([dis_loss, disc1], feed_dict = {i1 : i_1, i2 : i_2, learn_rate : l_r})

                print(test.shape)
                cv2.imwrite('./saved_imgs/gan_test'+str(j)+'.png', np.squeeze(test, axis = 3)[0])
                #Code to display gradients and other relevant stats on tensorboard
                #Will be under histogram tab, labelled OptimizeLoss
                # if j%500 == 0:
                #   writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(sess.graph, logdir = './tensorboard/1') #Change logdir for each run
                #   summary_str = sess.run(summary, feed_dict = {i1 : i_1, i2 : i_2, learn_rate : l_r})
                #   writer.add_summmary(summary_str, str(i)+': '+str(j))#Can change to one epoch only if necessary 
                #   writer.flush()

                if j % 12 == 0: #Prints loss statistics every 12th batch                    
                    #print('Epoch: '+str(i))
                    print('Generator Loss: '+str(gLoss))
                    print('Discriminator Loss: '+str(dLoss))

            self.save_model(sess, i)
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the shape in `tf.placeholder`? If that did not work, please clarify 1. Which network `conv1_1` is in, self.gen, self.disc, or self.disc_two? 2. How is `conv1_1` constructed? Using `tf.layer`?

Comment: Haha thanks specifying the shape did it.